# How to not show box-shadow on loading element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When I click on search button, I get a list of top tracks in my React-Redux app.

When the results are loading, I get the container box-shadow for each rendered track before the track is fully loaded. Like so:

[image]

**JS:**

```
const TopTracks = ({ track }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${track.id}`}
        title={track.name}
        width="300"
        height="80"
        allowtransparency="true"
        allow="encrypted-media"
        className="tracks"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopTracks;
```

**CSS:**

```
.tracks {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
}
```

**Is there any way for these shadow effects to not show before the element is fully loaded?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlexShinkevich answer I managed to come up with a compromise.

**JS:**

```
import { useState } from "react";

const TopTracks = ({ track }) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  // When Tracks are Loaded, Change the State to True
  const finishLoading = () => {
    setLoaded(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${track.id}`}
        title={track.name}
        width="300"
        height="80"
        allowtransparency="true"
        allow="encrypted-media"
        className={loaded ? "shadow" : "tracks"}
        onLoad={finishLoading}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopTracks;
```

**CSS:**

```
.tracks {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.shadow {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
}
```

I had to add a condition which checked if it was loaded and then changed the className accordingly.

I followed the answer of @AlexShinkevich but couldn't get the shadow and styles to render.

Although in this way the box-shadow spaces don't show when it's loading, they show with a slight delay after the tracks load.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could add additions class something like .shadowed and move the box-shadow property there.
Then you could add onLoad callback to the iframe and add or remove shadow depending on the status of loading.

```
const TopTracks = ({ track }) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  finishLoading() {
    setLoaded(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <iframe
        src={`https://open.spotify.com/embed/track/${track.id}`}
        title={track.name}
        width="300"
        height="80"
        allowtransparency="true"
        allow="encrypted-media"
        className={"track " + (loaded ? "shadowed": "")}
        onLoad={this.finishLoading}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopTracks;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a "loading" class of some sort that hides the element and then is removed once it is finished loading:

```
.tracks {
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;

    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease;
}

.tracks.loading {
    opacity: 0;
}
```